# composer install magento 2 module fails

Tags: module, magento2, git, bitbucket

I am trying to install a module which i created in magento 2 via composer, 
I have hosted the module on the bitbucket repository, and added the repository url in magento's composer.json,
When i try to install the module using the following

```
composer require package/module
```

The prompt asks for username and password for

```
repo.magento.com
```

I know that this is not the repository from which i need to download the module, but to proceed further i need to provide the username and password which i suppose are the same we use to login for https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

But somehow it gives the following error

```
E:\wamp\www\m2final>composer require package/module
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime
 performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username: email@example.com
      Password:
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.



require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
[--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-
packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packag
es>]...`
```

**-----EDIT-----**
After Clearing the above problems, i ran into another trouble, this has to do something with my repository structure,

I have created the repository names `Magento Repository`, and added the repository url in magento's `composer.json`

when i run the command composer require `package/module` i get the following error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package package/module at any version for your minimum-stability
   (alpha). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

This is my module's directory structure in bitbucket

[image]

```
The folders in are directly created in the repository root
```

This is my Module's composer.json

```
{
  "name": "package/module",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates a new page",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "extra":{
      "map":[
        [
          "*",
          "Package/Module"
        ]
      ]
    },
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~1.0.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Package\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html Section: Creating an authorization file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The username and password that you are using are wrong.

You need to use the public and private key generated from http://magentocommerce.com/

For generating the keys login to http://magentocommerce.com/

Goto My Account > Developers > Secure Keys and generate the new key.

Now run `composer require package/module` command as usual. Then when you get prompted for username and password do the following:

Enter the public key that you just created in user name field and private key in password field.

Click on enter, and the error should be gone.

Comment: I got that solved, however i got another problem, i have updated the question for that, please see the portion after ---EDIT---

Comment: may be this could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536978/how-to-solve-the-package-not-available-in-stable-enough-version-error-of-compo

Comment: I checked that, this does not sim to be the answer, maybe the problem is with my directory structure in the bitbucket repository?