# How to install module-sample-scss in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I'm trying to install [this module (magento/module-sample-scss)](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/module-sample-scss) in Magento 2 with composer as described [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/custom_preprocess.html#sample-sass-module), but with no success.

If I run this from the Magento root folder:

```
$ composer require magento/module-sample-scss
```

I get this error:

> Could not find package magento/module-sample-scss at any version for your minimum-stability (alpha). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

What am I doing wrong? Any help is really appreciated.

---

**Updates**

I tried with `"minimum-stability": "dev"` => Same error.

I tried to run `composer update`: it normally works and it say *Nothing to install or update*. But I get the same error when I try to install the module.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92340/composer-install-magento-2-module-fails or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85753/magento-2-uninstallable-set-of-packages-when-deploying-magento-sample-data. First run `composer update`

Comment: @AnkitShah thanks for references but those solutions doesn't help me (see my updates also). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is an issue with installing such modules with composer: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/issues/73

So I ended up to follow these steps to install the module:

1. Download the module as a .zip or with git clone
2. Under `/app/code`, create the directory `Magento/SampleScss` (the name of the directory must match the value of the module's /etc/module.xml).
3. Copy the contents of the module to that directory.
4. Add to composer any additional libs required by the module (take a look to the module's composer.json): `composer require leafo/scssphp:0.0.12`
5. Run `composer update`
6. Enable the module `php /bin/magento module:enable Magento_SampleScss`
7. Run `php /bin/magento setup:upgrade`